# Validate retrieved Firebase UID on server

Tags: java, firebase, angularfire2

I'm working with firebase and `angularfire2` which allows authentication with Facebook, Google+ and Twitter.

Now when a user authenticates like this, I get a response looking like the following.

```
{
"uid":"someUID",
"displayName":"ivaro18",
"photoURL":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-myPicture/photo.jpg",
"email":"myEmail@gmail.com",
"emailVerified":true,
"isAnonymous":false,
"apiKey":"aUUIDApiKey",
"appName":"[DEFAULT]",
"authDomain":"mydemo.firebase.com",
"stsTokenManager":{
    "apiKey":"aUUIDApiKey",
    "refreshToken":"AHugeRefreshToken",
    "accessToken":"aHugeAccessToken",
    "expirationTime":1481297860666
},
"redirectEventId":null
}
```

The authentication works and the user data can be retrieved (left out `providerData` because it wasn't usefull in the JSON - won't be used)

I will send this `uid` or `apiKey` to my REST API (via Angular2's `http.post`), but to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks I want to validate the token.

So (**edit**: added the `if` and `isComplete`

```
    @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        println("yes")
        val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setServiceAccount(
                        FileInputStream("C:/Users/ivaro18/firebase.json")
                ).setDatabaseUrl("https://myDemo.firebaseio.com")
                .build()
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)

        if(
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken("whatToken?")
                .addOnSuccessListener(OnSuccessListener<FirebaseToken>() {
                    @Override
                    fun onSuccess(decodedToken: FirebaseToken) {
                        val uid = decodedToken.getUid()
                        println("UID:::" + uid)
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    fun onFailure(e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                })
                .addOnCompleteListener(OnCompleteListener<FirebaseToken>() {
                    @Override
                    fun onComplete(token: FirebaseToken) {
                        println("Token: " + token)
                    }
        }).isComplete()) {
           println("verification completed");
        }
        println("ok")
    }
```

But this code outputs (Kotlin btw, almost same syntax as Java and it can run Java code)

```
yes
verficiation completed
ok
```

and then terminates after a while. I'd expect one of the listeners to fire? What is wrong with the code?

And what ID from that JSON array should I be validating within the `FirebaseAuth`?

**edit**

The `uid` part of the JSON is the same UID mentioned in the Firebase Authentication page (shown below)

[image: Firebase Console]

I want to check if the `UID` is equal to the `UID` on the console. (preferrably by sending the `apiKey` and `accessToken` but just checking if the `uid` is the same would be sufficient for now.

Comment: If I had to guess I would suspect that the `FirebaseAuth` instance does not keep the main thread alive until the listeners have been triggered (and hence your program terminates after the second `println`). Have you tried adding a `while` loop to wait until the operation is done (e.g.: using [`isComplete`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/tasks/Task.html#isComplete())?

Comment: Wrapping the statement in an `if(.....verfifyToken........isComplete()){ println("complete"); }` prints `yes` `complete` `ok` I'll edit the question with new code

Comment: `isSuccesful` returns `false` with every `id` found within the JSON object

Comment: Here is a java example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418472/how-do-i-secure-my-google-cloud-endpoints-apis-with-firebase-token-verification/38423163#38423163

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseToken
import com.google.firebase.tasks.Task
import com.google.firebase.tasks.Tasks
import java.io.FileInputStream

class Firebase {
val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setServiceAccount(
        FileInputStream("your/url/to/firebase.json")
    ).setDatabaseUrl("https://your-application.firebaseio.com")
    .build()

    fun validateToken(accessToken: String) {
        val firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options))

        val authTask: Task<FirebaseToken> = firebaseAuth.verifyIdToken(accessToken)
        try{
            Tasks.await(authTask)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            //handle exception
        }
        // retrieve uid/email/name
        authTask.getResult().uid
    }
}
```

And like Stefan said, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418472/how-do-i-secure-my-google-cloud-endpoints-apis-with-firebase-token-verification/38423163#38423163) Java example.